# Responsive image with CSS margin top and bottom fixed in pixels?

Tags: image, css, margin, fixed

I tried with this but it's not working.. I want the image to change its size proportionately but margin-top and margin-bottom to be fixed in pixels.

```
#imagenslide img {

    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px!important;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;

}
```

Any help please?  Thanks!

Comment: CSS is useless without HTML, create a fiddle as well please.

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/RxbBM/ ?

Comment: Thanks, but margin-bottom it's not working.


This is the website and an image I'm trying to be centered (margin-top and margin-bottom 150px)

http://www.pepapoch.testlink.es/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
#imagenslide img {

    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px!important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;

}
```

or you can also use `min-width` css property also..
Also try to use width in % for responsive..

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. I commented the first post. This is the link to the website www.pepapoch.testlink.es

Comment: @AbelAbad use this css for the image
'margin-top: 150px 20% 240px !important;
width: 60%;
height: auto;'
You dont need to keep that 'position:fixed' on this image..

Comment: also after that correct the **postion and width**, define a proper width to its parent div..so that the image accordingly adopt 'width' from its parent 'div'
before all that arrange all the **divs** in a proper hierarchy. right now its not in an order..

Comment: Or if you still wanna use 'position:fixed' for some reason, so remove margin from that, and use 'top' 'left' css property to adjust its position..

Comment: Thank you. I think margin bottom is ignored because of width:60%... still not solved. http://www.pepapoch.testlink.es/

Comment: Its working dear..its already getting resized on different size sizes..with fixed margin in bottom/top..now what is left...?? elaborate your query after this stage...
Also still your HTML structure is not correct. the image have got hidden behind all the dis..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close, but I think it's more simple than you think. Try:

```
<img id="imagenslide"src="http://placehold.it/350x150">

#imagenslide { 
    margin: 100px 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uP7z/)